# Why do i have multiple CPU's, and not Cores

Tags: cpu

Maybe I am just getting confused but as of my understanding, there is one CPU that has multiple Cores inside of it. [Random CPU Image i found on Google](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ieHEq.png)

When I enter `lscpu` (or open [System Monitor](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/SystemMonitor)), i get told that i have 16 CPU's [Screenshot of lscpu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o893j.png)

So now i am super confused, as `lscpu` also tells me, that I just have [12 Cores](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TX2eP.png).
These things just don't make sense for me.

Comment: Per the duplicate: "The term "CPU" can be ambiguous. When people buy "a CPU", they buy a CPU package. When they inspect "CPU scaling", they talk about logical cores. The reason for this is that for most practical purposes dual-core processor behaves like two processor system, ie. system that has two CPU sockets and two CPU single core packages installed to them"

Comment: It's one of those weird dualities. A "core" is *technically* a CPU, but a CPU may not be *just* a core.